# Cannot get data from stored procedure with SqlQuery

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is the stored procedure:

```
public partial class AddedSP: DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateStoredProcedure("dbo.GetTopRecommendingUsers"
          // These are stored procedure parameters
          ,null,
          // Here is the stored procedure body
          @" SET NOCOUNT ON;
             BEGIN
             SELECT promoter.Id, promoter.Email, promoter.PhoneNumber, promoter.UserName, promoter.FirstName, promoter.LocationId, promoter.RegionId, promoter.ProfilePhotoId, promoter.LastName, COUNT(u.RecommendedById) AS Recommendations
             FROM AspNetUsers AS promoter 
             INNER JOIN AspNetUsers AS u ON u.RecommendedById = promoter.Id
             GROUP BY promoter.Id, promoter.Email, promoter.PhoneNumber,promoter.RegionId, promoter.UserName, promoter.LocationId, promoter.ProfilePhotoId, promoter.FirstName, promoter.LastName
             ORDER BY COUNT(u.RecommendedById) DESC
             END");
    }
    public override void Down()
    {
        DropStoredProcedure("dbo.GetTopRecommendingUsers");
    }
}
```

This is my class:

```
public class RecommenderViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LocationId { get; set; }
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
    public string ProfilePhotoId { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Recommendations { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the method that makes the call:

```
    public List<RecommenderViewModel> GetTopRecommendingUsers()
    {
        List<RecommenderViewModel> model = new List<RecommenderViewModel>();
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            model = context.Database.SqlQuery<RecommenderViewModel>("GetTopRecommendingUsers").ToList();
        }
        return model;
    }
```

But I get an empty list (Count=0) in the model variable of my `GetTopRecommendingUsers()` method.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe you have no data? Have you run the procedure in SSMS and verified the correct results?

Comment: Ive already executed the query in SSMS and it returns about three rows of data

Comment: Do you really need to have all those fields grouped? It seems the id is enough.

Comment: Im not sure why but when i tried to execute the query in SSMS it'd give me an error and adding the grouping fields worked with solving that problem.

Comment: @Steve The GROUP BY is correct.  SQL will expect that every output field in a grouped query is either part of an aggregation or included in the GROUP BY clause

Comment: @Steve Unless you are using a weird DBMS like MySql or MariaDB, you must specify every column. This is why a correlated subquery is often clearer and easier

Comment: Could be wrong, but do you have the parameters for `CreateStoredProcedure` backwards? I think `body` is the second parameter

Comment: @Charlieface that was the problem, removing the null solved it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the ConnectString ? might be I think you access another database in local with same name of your database.